# Какие основные различия между системным администрированием CentOs/RedHat и Ubuntu server?

Tags: администрирование

Отличия лишь в в установке программ и изменении файловой структуры?

Comment: Ну собственно да, *nix, он и в Африке *nix, конечно при переходе с linux на freeBSD или что то другое *nix'овое побольше манов придется смотреть а так то они все жутко похожи.

Answer (score 1):

никаких серьёзных отличий.

это всего лишь разные дистрибутивы одной и той же операционной системы *gnu/linux*.

Comment: Поскольку ответ попал в очередь проверок, напишу пару слов проверяющим. Да, ответ очень короткий. Но он полностью соответствует вопросу и отвечает на него.